# Exactness of functors as "iff"; conjecture about bifunctors

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory, abelian-categories

The definition of (right-/left-) exact functors is that they preserve (right-/left-) exactness of SESs. However, for some certain nice functors, as $\def\Hom{\text{Hom}\,}\Hom (A,-)$ and $A\otimes-$ we have even more: namely that if a SES sequence $$\mathcal S:0\rightarrow M'\rightarrow M\rightarrow M''\rightarrow 0$$ of modules remains (right-/left-) exact after homing (or tensoring) with any module A, then the sequence $\mathcal S$ was exact  to begin with. The proof I have of these two examples is made in a rather *ad-hoc* manner and I was wondering if there is a more general proof.

To illustrate this, let me give a sketch of how we show that if $\Hom(A,\mathcal S)$ is exact at $\Hom(A,M')$, then $\mathcal S$ is exact at $M'$. Suppose not; then consider the sequence $\Hom(N,\mathcal S)$, where $N$ is the kernel of $M'\rightarrow M$. It is not exact.

Another example that I'd like to add is that of taking the stalk of a sheaf . Since this is a right-exact functor, a SES in sheaves $$0\rightarrow\mathcal F\rightarrow \mathcal G \rightarrow 0 \rightarrow 0 \tag{*}$$ would yield a right-exact sequence $$0\rightarrow\mathcal F_p\rightarrow \mathcal G_p \rightarrow 0. \tag{**}$$

Now, I'm tempted to say that if (**) is exact for all $p$ then (*) was in fact exact to start with because this is very similar to the property that I alluded to above. This is in fact true, as I tried to show in my other [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/540574/proving-that-morphism-of-sheaves-is-iso-iff-induced-morphism-on-stalks-is-iso). My question is: is there a purely categorical proof that generalizes all these facts?

I'd even conjecture that, under some exactness properties, if a bifunctor $\mathcal B(-,-)$ is right-/left-  <strike>exact</strike>  adjoint in its second argument, then the functor $\prod_A \mathcal B(A,-)$ (i.e. $\mathcal B$ parametrized by a family) reflects exactness (i.e. it enjoys the property that if $\prod_A \mathcal B(A,\mathcal S)$ is exact, then $\mathcal S$ was exact).

Comment: Those sequences are not what are usually called short exact. They are a term too short.

Comment: You can add an extra zero to the left of (\*) if you like. But I think my point is still clear, right?

Comment: In many categories (I won't say all as I am not familiar enough with general abelian categories to know how general this is), the sort of exact sequence you have here simply corresponds to an isomorphism. And all functors preserve isomorphisms.

Comment: Also, if a short exact sequence is preserved by $\mathrm{Hom}(A, -)$ for all $A$ then it must be a split exact sequence.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: do you mean the sequence (\*)? There, I wanted to say that (\**) for all $p$ implies (\*), so the fact that functors preserve isomorphisms doesn't help me.

Comment: @ZhenLin: I think you can drop exact in your hypothesis. If a short sequence $\mathcal S$ yields a short exact sequence $\def\Hom{\text{Hom}\,}\Hom(A,\mathcal S)$ for all $A$ then, in particular, $\Hom(A, \mathcal S)$ are all left-exact, so, by what I claimed, $\mathcal S$ is exact to start with. Then you can deduce from what you said that it is indeed split exact. So I think that my point is somehow prior to yours and I failed to see how your point helps.

Comment: No, that's not true. There are a couple of mistakes in your reasoning there.

Comment: @ZhenLin Do you mean "remains exact" by "is preserved"? If yes, I don't see any mistakes in my argument, and I kindly ask you to point out to me where they are (I've mulled over it for a while now). Again, if $\def\operatorname{Hom}\Hom(A,\mathcal S)$ is exact for all $A$, then from the result I mentioned in my question $\mathcal S$ is exact. Hence, we can now say $\mathcal S$ is preserved by by $\Hom(A,-)$. It follows that $\mathcal S$ is split.

Comment: It is true that $\mathrm{Hom}(A, -)$ is left exact for all $A$ and it is true that $\mathrm{Hom}(A, \mathcal{S})$ being exact for all $A$ implies $\mathcal{S}$ is split exact. But these two facts are unrelated.

Comment: @ZhenLin I reedited my question so that it is clearer now. I think we were talking past each other. In my last comments I just meant that in what you said before "if a short exact sequence is preserved by $\mathrm{Hom}(A, -)$ for all $A$ then it must be a split exact sequence" you could have suppressed the exact and thus say "if a **short sequence** is preserved by $\mathrm{Hom}(A, -)$ for all $A$ then it must be a split exact sequence". I still believe that the reasoning I gave was sound,  but I don't see how splitting or not was relevant here as you proposed.

Comment: Your conjecture about bifunctors is obviously false: take the functor that sends everything to zero. It is exact but fails to have any interesting reflection properties.

Comment: Your new conjecture is still obviously false: the constant zero functor has both a left adjoint and a right adjoint.